# I installed a maven sources and javadoc package but its not being detected by Eclipse

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I did:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$d/s/_java/spymemcached/build/spymemcached-2.8-custom-javadoc.jar -DgroupId=spy -DartifactId=spymemcached -Dversion=2.8custom -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dclassifier=javadoc

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$d/s/_java/spymemcached/build/spymemcached-2.8-custom-sources.jar -DgroupId=spy -DartifactId=spymemcached -Dversion=2.8custom -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dclassifier=sources
```

But Eclipse is not attempting to detect these sources and Javadoc for this package. Please let me know how to fix this.

I am aware I can add the sources and Javadoc manually with Eclipse.

**Fixed:** don't specify `/cygdrive/` when using Cygwin to execute `mvn`, use `s:/`.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using? Do you have configured eclipse to use your installed Maven? Is the cache in Eclipse build, so are you able to lookup resources in your internal repository?

Comment: Fixed: don't specify /cygdrive/s when using cygwin to execute mvn, use s:/path... Mvn didn't actually add the jar because the path got mangled into: S:/cygdrive/s/path...

Comment: Could you write an answer on your own, and accept that in 2 days, so others will know, that you have solved your question?

Comment: One comment to your question: It is not clear, why you run `mvn` from CygWin. It can be run perfectly from windows console.

Comment: Because I have cygwin open all the time, no other reason. Sure, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

MetaChrome Oct 15 '11 at 9:52:

> Fixed: don't specify /cygdrive/ when using cygwin to execute mvn, use s:/